# How to have a single button used for multiple events Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

For a portfolio project, I am attempting to create a game using windows forms, and I am having this issue that I can't seem to figure out,

I have a game screen that requires the user to input the answer to a question and then hit the next button to set the answer = to a variable or do some sort of action, and then have that button also output the next question to the listbox.

Is there a sort of break I can incorporate that will make the next listbox output wait for the button click? if so how would I do this, I can't seem to find anything about it anywhere.

```
Public Class frmGame
    Public Sub frmGame_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load ' main game window, dim's variables
        lstOutput.Items.Add("Please enter your name")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click 'Next button, advances the game
        lstOutput.ClearSelected()
        Dim name As String = txtInput.Text

        lstOutput.Items.Add("Are you a boy or a girl, enter the number of your choice")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click 'Next button, advances the game
        lstOutput.ClearSelected()
        Dim name As String = txtInput.Text

        lstOutput.Items.Add("e")
        Dim gender As String = txtInput.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnReset_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnReset.Click 'clears textbox for user input

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You have two handlers defined for the same button. They will both run when it's clicked. It's very unclear what you want to do, but it appears it might involve either one big `if ... else if...` in the only click handler that represents the possible steps in your program, or several handlers that you attach and detach as needed, or even switching to console project type given the type of interaction you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want the program to be able to ask a question, have the user type the answer to that question in the textbox, then hit the "next" button and have a new question appear. I'm guessing doing a console app would be easier due to that because it will allow me to have a pause between questions waiting for enter

Answer (score 0):

> I want the program to be able to ask a question, have the user type
>   the answer to that question in the textbox, then hit the "next" button
>   and have a new question appear

Create class which represents question-answer data

```
Public Class Question    
    Public ReadOnly Property Text As String
    Public Property Answer As String

    Public Sub New(text As String)
        Me.Text = text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then initialize collection of questions and in "Next" button click move through whole collection of questions.

```
Public Class frmGame
    Private _questions As List(Of Question)
    Private _currentQuestionIndex As Integer = -1

    Public Sub frmGame_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _questions = Return New List(Of Question) From
        {
            new Question("Please enter your name"),
            new Question("Question 1"),
            new Question("Question 2"),
            new Question("Last question")
        }

        MoveToNextQuestion()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ButtonNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
        Dim currentQuestion = _questions[_currentQuestionIndex]
        currentQuestion.Answer = txtInput.Text

        If IsCurrentQuestionLast() Then
            ProcessAnswers()
        Else
            MoveToNextQuestion()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub MoveToNextQuestion()
        _currentQuestionIndex += 1

        txtInput.Text = Stirng.Empty
        txtQuestionText.Text = _questions[_currentQuestionIndex]
    End Sub

    Private Function IsCurrentQuestionLast()
        Return _currentQuestionIndex = _questions.Count - 1
    End Function

    Private Sub ProcessAnswers()
        For Each question In _questions
            ' Do something with question.Answer
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```